# Can you extract line segment length from image FFT?

Tags: python, image-processing, fft

I am trying to determine the average angle and length of a bunch of line segments in an image, like the one below.

[image: image with angled line segments]

This is a toy image--the real data I am working with is much nosier. I have gotten good results for the average angle by applying a Radon transform to the FFT of the image--see below.

[image: fft of image above]

[image: radon transform showing dominant angle]

I intuitively think there must be a way to also extract the average length using the fft of the image, but I don't know how. Any help from "nope you can't do that using FFT" to "here's how to do that using FFT" would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I have tried applying a Hough transform to the Canny output of the image, but my data is noisy to the point that the output is not reliable.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But you could use a granulometry, for example as described here: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/20215077/ -- if all lines are at the same orientation, and you know the orientation, the computational cost decreases significantly.

Comment: If the lines don't intersect, like in your toy example, then it's quite simple to segment them out and do a normal binary object length measurement. Granulometries are useful mostly for messy situations where segmentation is not easy.